# Calculate KPIs of riders daily using Mongoose and Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongoose, optimization

I'm developing a feature which requires to calculate riders KPIs daily at the end of the day. This includes calculating rider's late and early login rates, orders delivered under and over a certain hour, cancellation acceptance and rejection rate.

Currently our system holds 10,000 riders' data. What will be the best approach to calculate this without any downtime? The tech I'm using is Node.js and Mongoose.

Currently, I'm fetching all the riders through [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) at the end of the day using pagination and then calculate the above mentioned scenarios, but I'm worried if the data of riders increased, which is the possibility, the system will get slow.

Comment: What is "[KPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KPI)" in this context? *Key performance indicator* seems too grandiose.

Comment: By KPI I meant total orders accepted, delivered, cancelled, acceptance, rejection, cancellation rate, total hours planned and actual hours worked, orders delivered under 30,60,90 minutes and over 90 minute by a rider over a specified time period